# creating date with integer then casting back to integer loses precision in JAVA?

Tags: java, date, casting, int, precision

Is it possible to lose precision in this case?

```
int X =  (some integer number);
Date D = new Date(X * 1000);
int Y  = (int)(D.getTime())/1000;
```

I would believe that Y would always be the same as X as long as X is some integer value.  Is that correct?

Comment: `X * 1000` could overflow... The problem would not be a loss of precision but a (seemingly) random date...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No!you're not correct!
replace the line `Date D = new Date(X * 1000);`

with `Date D = new Date(X * 1000L)`;

Answer (score 0):

Use long (64 bit) numbers not integers (32 bit) numbers.  If you use integers it may overflow (go from positive to negative).  See this link for details https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM00-J.+Detect+or+prevent+integer+overflow